# Get Account field level permissions for specific field + salesforce

Tags: apex, community

Based on many examples on the internet, I tried this to get the Account obj fields permission details based on the profile. The below is the query executed but unfortunately, the query return empty data.I want to get the standard and custom field permission details on the Account obj. Can anyone pls help if I did anything wrong here?

```
List<FieldPermissions> fpList = new List<FieldPermissions>();
fpList = 
[SELECT Field, SObjectType, PermissionsRead, PermissionsEdit 
FROM fieldPermissions 
WHERE SObjectType = 'Account' AND 
Field='Account.Name' 
AND parentId in ( SELECT id 
                  FROM permissionSet 
                  WHERE PermissionSet.Profile.Name = 'System Administrator') ];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fields which are required by the system, e.g. Account.Name, cannot be queried, as they are always editable and required (given the user can edit the object itself and and any specific record). Try using Account.Industry as a better example:

```
SELECT Field, SObjectType, PermissionsRead, PermissionsEdit 
FROM fieldPermissions 
WHERE SObjectType = 'Account' AND 
Field='Account.Industry' 
AND parentId in ( SELECT id 
                  FROM permissionSet 
                  WHERE PermissionSet.Profile.Name = 'System Administrator')
```

You should get back a result for that field, assuming that profile can view or edit the field. Note that you won't get a result back if the given profile cannot view or edit the field (i.e. it is a hidden field).

Comment: Gotcha. Why can't query by Custom fields? I tried with Custom fields, it is giving empty results. Any idea ?

Comment: @RKCY custom fields work, too. Make sure you include the namespace, if any, and keep in mind that hidden fields won't return a result.

Comment: I tried with the custom field, by passing the value like  Field= 'Account.Email__c' as email is the custom field. But it didn't bring the result.

Comment: @RKCY I don't know what else to tell you. Either there's no field access, or you didn't include the namespace. Does your Org have a namespace? Does the field? Check the field's full API name in the wsdl or in Setup.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I see the custom fields are visible to the account and see the read and write access in the permissionset. But I could not able to fetch the field details by using API name via apex code. Also, I don't see any specific namespace for the fields and what else should I check. Sorry if I asked you a dumb question.